# cannot find symbol error for the Thread.sleep function

Tags: java

```
 import java.util.*;

public class myProcess extends Thread
{

private Random R = new Random();
private int id;

public myProcess(int i){
    id = i;
}

private void delay(int value){
    try{
        sleep(R.nextInt(value));
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("Exception caught");
    }
}

public void run(){
    // some code   
}

public static void main(String [] args){

   // some code
}


 }
```

When I compile the above code, the following error shows up

```
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method sleep(int)
  location: class myProcess
```

I can't seem to find the solution.I tried to change the sleep function to Thread.sleep, but it just changes the error location to class Thread. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Do you have another class called `Thread` on your classpath? If so remove it

Comment: how do i widen the conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have another type called `Thread` which is not `java.lang.Thread` in the same package and on the classpath of your running application. If this is something you wanted, then you need to use the fully qualified name of the `java.lang.Thread` class to invoke its `sleep` method

```
java.lang.Thread.sleep(R.nextInt(value));
```

Comment: oh wow this works. Can you explain why my code does not work? I thought I extended the Thread class when I declared myProcess

Comment: @user3277633 By providing a class named `Thread` (you still haven't confirmed this though) you are shadowing the `Thread` class in the `java.lang` package which gets implicitly imported. Your `Thread` class doesn't have such a `sleep` method.